# Javac -parameters

Tags: java, reflection, javac

What are the downsides to using the `-parameters` argument to javac (with Java 8)?

I'm wanting to use it to remove a bit more boilerplate in some Jackson data classes and this seems like a good way to do it. The main disadvantage I see is that it makes the compiled classes larger. Though not by much. One project I've been working with:

- jar size without `-parameters`: 107k
- jar size with `-parameters`: 110k

Are there other known downsides?

Comment: I can't see how there would be - it's simply keeping the variable names of the parameters in the constructors / methods rather than replacing them with synthetic versions. That's not going to affect speed, reliability or anything else I can think of - it just takes a bit more space to store them.

Comment: I found one more: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-758. If you use `-parameters` and are using an older version of spring data jpa (1.8.1 and earlier it appears) and use offset based query parameter (e.g. `?1`) then it throws an error. So there may be libraries out there which don't play nice with it.

Comment: well that's not the fault of `-parameters`