# Drawbacks of javac -parameters flag

Tags: java-8, javac

I want to try some frameworks features that required names of parameter in runtime, so I need to compile my app with `-parameters` and it will store the names of parameter in JVM byte code.

Which drawbacks except the size of jar/war exist of this parameter usage?

Comment: This will be surprising.

Comment: Already asked here but without answer: [Javac -parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489323/javac-parameters)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The addition of parameter names to the class file format is covered by [JEP 118](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/118), which was delivered in Java 8. There was a little bit of discussion about why inclusion of parameter names was made optional in OpenJDK email threads [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/enhanced-metadata-spec-discuss/2013-May/000200.html) and [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/enhanced-metadata-spec-discuss/2013-May/000202.html). Briefly, the stated reasons to make parameter names optional are concerns about class file size, compatibility surface, and exposure of sensitive information.

The issue of compatibility surface deserves some additional discussion. One of the threads linked above says that changing a parameter name is a binary compatible change. This is true, but only in the strict context of the JVM's notion of binary compatibility. That is, changing a parameter name of a method will never change whether or not that method can be linked by the JVM. But the statement doesn't hold for compatibility in general.

Historically, parameter names have been treated like local variable names. (They are, after all, local in scope.) You could change them at will and nothing outside the method will be affected. But if you enable reflective access to parameter names, suddenly you can't change a name without thinking about what other parts of the program might be using it. Worse, there's nothing that can tell you unless you have strict test cases for all uses of parameter names, or you have a really good static analyzer that can find these cases (I'm not aware of one).

The comments linked to a question about using Jackson (a JSON processing library) which has a feature that maps method parameter names to JSON property names. This may be quite convenient, but it also means that if you change a parameter name, JSON binding might break. Worse, if the program is generating JSON structures based on Java method parameter names, then changing a method parameter name might silently change a data format or wire protocol. Clearly, in such an environment, using this feature reliably means that you have to have very good tests, plus comments sprinkled around the code indicating what parameter names mustn't be changed.

Answer (score 6):

The **only** thing is the size of the `.class` that will change, since the bytecode will now contain more information:

```
public class DeleteMe3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    private static void go(String s) {
    }
}
```

For example this will contain information about paramter names like so:

```
private static void go(java.lang.String);
   descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_STATIC
   Code:
     stack=0, locals=1, args_size=1
       0: return
     LineNumberTable:
       line 11: 0
   MethodParameters:
     Name                           Flags
     s
```

This `MethodParameters` will simply not be present without `-parameters`.

There might be frameworks that don't play nice with this. Here is one [Spring Data JPA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-758). I know about it because we hit it some time ago and had to upgrade (I have not been faced with any other from there on).

Comment: The bytecode is viewed with `javap -v`, if anyone wonders.